# Computing the number of $\sigma$-algebra.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be a set. How many $\sigma$-algebras of subsets of $X$ contain exactly $m$ elements?

Any hints for how to begin a solution to this problem are greatly appreciated.

My initial approach is as follows:

Let $|X| = n$, then $|P(X)| = 2^n$
Thus our count is given by
$\binom{2^n}{m}$

We have no information as to the cardinality of $X$.

Comment: How big is $X$? What are your own thoughts so far?

Comment: Why did you choose $5$?  Odd numbers are a little special.

Comment: That is to say, any $m$ subsets form a $\sigma$-algebra?  I don't think so.

Comment: Not every $m$-tuple of subsets of $X$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.  Actually, the "$\sigma$" is not needed: if the set is finite, you only have to worry about finite unions and intersections.

Comment: Try making examples for small values of |X| and see if a pattern emerges.  I would count all the $\sigma$-algebras (or as Robert Israel points out, all the algebras) for say, $|X|\leq6$ and see what turns up.

Comment: Please, don't deface your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algebras (and thus $\sigma$-algebras) of subsets of a finite set correspond to partitions of the set.  If $P = \{P_1, \ldots, P_k\}$ is a partition of $X$, i.e. disjoint nonempty subsets whose union is $X$, then you get an algebra consisting of the $2^k$ unions of subsets of $P$.  So if $m = 2^k$, the number of algebras of subsets of $X$ is the number of partitions of $X$ into $k$ parts.  If $m$ is not a power of $2$, there are no algebras with cardinality $m$.

Comment: So [Stirling's numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) give the values.